# int countervalue = i.getIntExtra("Count", 0); makes app crash

Tags: android, crash

```
    int countervalue = i.getIntExtra("Count", 10);
```

I have this line of code in a different activity when someone clicks a button they go to that activity. Without this line of code the app runs perfectly.

Here is the whole code for the activity:

```
  package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
Intent i = getIntent();
int userchoice;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    int countervalue = i.getIntExtra("Count", 0);
    String[] values = {"Apple($20)-                Generates $40/sec", 
    "Second", "Third"};
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        }

    });


}
}
```

Comment: Add the error stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

initialize `i = getIntent();` inside `onCreate()` method

right before `int countervalue = i.getIntExtra("Count", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use bundle such as

First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("int",20);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in Second Activity use this

```
Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = i.getInt("int");
```

Answer (score 0):

Vyacheslav's answer is correct, but here's a little more info.

When you write:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent i = getIntent();
}
```

Your `Intent i` will be intialized as soon as your `SecondActivity` instance is created, and it will be set to the results of the `getIntent()` method.

If you look at the source for this method, you see:

```
public Intent getIntent() {
    return mIntent;
}
```

At the time your `SecondActivity` instance is created, `mIntent` is null. So your activity is behaving as though you had written this instead:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent i = null;
}
```

The solution, as Vyacheslav said, is to initialize the `i` variable later on. Anywhere inside `onCreate()` (after the `super` call) is a fine place to do so, but waiting until just before your `i.getIntExtra("Count", 0)` call will work as well.